# Set the default program to PDF Studio 8 Pro

Tags: kubuntu, kde, pdf

I just installed Kubuntu 14.04 KDE on my laptop, and installed a PDF Studio 8 Pro which I purchased from qoppa.com. I have the same program installed on my other computer, which runs on Linux Mint 16 KDE operating system. On my Linux Mint computer, I can set the default to open a pdf file with PDF studio automatically. That is accomplished by right clicking on a pdf file, and choose PDF studio, which is located under "Office", and set the default so you can open a pdf file by simply double clicking the file.

On Kubuntu 14.04 KDE, the PDF studio is not located in the office, or any where else that I could find. It is located in "Home" directory, and in order to open a pdf file with PDFstudio 8, I have to open the home directory, open the pdfstudio 8 folder, choose the pdfstudio 8 desktop, open it first, and then choose the file that I want to open. Even though that I have made a short-cut to the pdfstudio in my panel, but it still takes a few seconds. Verses double clicking the file, which is instantaneous. Any suggestion will greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on a PDF → Properties → File Type Options
2. In Application Preference Order → +Add
3. Instead of selecting from that tree view, Use browser button
   [image]
4. Browse to PDF Studio 8 executable